# File Upload Using Multer and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

I am working on an Image Upload server using multer and mongodb following This GeeksForGeeks Post:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/upload-and-retrieve-image-on-mongodb-using-mongoose/

I did everything same as in this post but my localhost server is just loading and loading.

My Project Structure :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1NhC.png

App.js:

```
// Step 1 - set up express & mongoose

var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
require('dotenv/config');
// Step 2 - connect to the database

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, err => {
        console.log('connected')
    });
// Step 3 - code was added to ./models.js

// Step 4 - set up EJS

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Set EJS as templating engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
// Step 5 - set up multer for storing uploaded files

var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
// Step 6 - load the mongoose model for Image

var imgModel = require('./model');
// Step 7 - the GET request handler that provides the HTML UI

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    imgModel.find({}, (err, items) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send('An error occurred', err);
        }
        else {
            res.render('imagesPage', { items: items });
        }
    });
});
// Step 8 - the POST handler for processing the uploaded file

app.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {

    var obj = {
        name: req.body.name,
        desc: req.body.desc,
        img: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: 'image/png'
        }
    }
    imgModel.create(obj, (err, item) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            // item.save();
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
// Step 9 - configure the server's port

var port = process.env.PORT || '3000'
app.listen(port, err => {
    if (err)
        throw err
    console.log('Server listening on port', port)
})
```

Model.js:

```
// Step 3 - this is the code for ./models.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    desc: String,
    img:
    {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
});

//Image is a model which has a schema imageSchema

module.exports = new mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```

.env:

```
MONGO_URL = mongodb://localhost/mongo
PORT = 5500
```

imagesPage.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Uploading</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>To Upload Image on mongoDB</h1>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Image Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"
                    value="" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="desc">Image Description</label>
                <textarea id="desc" name="desc" value="" rows="2"
                        placeholder="Description" required>
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="image">Upload Image</label>
                <input type="file" id="image"
                    name="image" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <h1>Uploaded Images</h1>
    <div>
        <% items.forEach(function(image) { %>
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src="data:image/<%=image.img.contentType%>;base64,
                    <%=image.img.data.toString('base64')%>">
                <div>
                    <h5><%= image.name %></h5>
                    


<p><%= image.desc %></p>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please tell what i am doing wrong.
I very new to backend so I don't know what to do
Thanks

Comment: your server has to respond in each case, in Step 8, in the create model error case (if-else), the `if` body does not return a response

Comment: So I have to add a res.send() in if statement?

Comment: Added this : res.send('Error Occurred : ' + err) but still no progress. It just loading and loading and not getting loaded

Comment: I believe your code goes to infinite redirect because of the `res.redirect('/');` line, try replacing it with `res.render` or `res.send`

Comment: Replaced res.redirect with res.render but still no progress